# Netlify: if changes on this folder deploy to different repository (?)

Tags: netlify, vuepress, netlify-cms

Here's the scenario:

I have two Vuepress website repositories on Github using NetlifyCMS with the deployment on Netlify, each one for a different website.

Site 1: *guidesABC.blah.com*  ->  *RepositoryABC*

Site 2: *guidesA.blah.com*  ->  *RepositoryA*

The guide A is in both repositories.

Is there a way I can use the Functions on Netlify to check if the changes are done on the folder A the changes happen on the RepositoryA as well?

What I don't want to do is go to site/Admin on guideABC - do the changes on the *md file, publish and do the same on the site guideA copying and pasting the code.

Thank You

Comment: I have to ask: are you 100% certain you need to be duplicating your content like this in the first place?

Comment: (Happy to help you figure out a way to avoid the duplicate repo situation if so.)

Comment: Yes, It's a bit unusual but the content needs to be duplicated but managed only from one of these sites.

Comment: It'll take a fair amount of Git-over-API code no matter how you do it, Eg. creating and pushing blobs, trees, commits, etc. I'd love to see Netlify CMS backend logic packaged to serve direct use cases like this, but it isn't there yet.